# Algolia's advanced syntax highlight issue with single quote char

Tags: algolia, laravel-scout

I have an issue with the Algolia's advanced syntax and highlighted results. When I put a single quote char "Apostrophe" (') in the request, it does match my records but the result isn't highlighted unless I escape the single quote char.

In the following example, I only have one record in my index. The advanced syntax is on and title attribute is searchable.

[image]

When I type the title in the query, the highlight seems to be good.

[image]

When I put double quotes around the query (to activate exact match from the advanced syntax) it does match the result but the title isn't highlighted.

[image]

BUT if I escape the single quote with a backslash it does highlight it!

[image]

Is that a bug from Algolia (since I'm using there own query system)? Did I misconfigured something?

It seems weird to me to escape some chars and if it would be the case, shouldn't Algolia do it? Or which chars should I escape?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See also the question on Algolia's forum https://discourse.algolia.com/t/algolias-advanced-syntax-highlight-issue-with-single-quote-char/8038

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** It's a bug from Algolia being fixed

I've just got an answer from Algolia's support team, here it is

> You did in fact, find a highlighting bug, and we have created an issue
>   (tracked it internally as ticket 2473)
>
> We will keep you informed when the issue is fixed.

So as they said, I'll keep you updated when I will.